# If a thrown weapon has only normal range, does it have unlimited range?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue

As i was reading the Soulknife Rogue feature "Psychic Blades" from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything:

> ...This magic blade is a simple melee weapon with the finesse and thrown properties. It has a normal range of 60 feet and **no long range**, and on a hit, it deals psychic damage equal to 1d6 plus the ability modifier you used for the attack roll. The blade vanishes immediately after it hits or misses its target, and it leaves no mark on its target if it deals damage.

Following that, i look at the PHB for the rules on range for weapons:

> A weapon that can be used to make a ranged attack has a range shown in parentheses after the ammunition or thrown property. The range lists two numbers. The first is the weapon's normal range in feet, and the second indicates the weapon's long range. When attacking a target beyond normal range, you have disadvantage on the attack roll. You can't attack a target beyond the weapon's long range.

So, the psychic blades from the Soulknife have unlimited range but with disadvantage or only can attack on the normal range?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate as it has been asked before. This is okay, duplicates serve to point others to the answers they are looking for.